# Laravel/php - creating an array of boolean values from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, checkbox

I"m attempting to create an array of a user's selections from 4 checkboxes, where the values are boolean (1 or 0). Here's where I'm at so far:

```
$selections = [
        'marketing' => $request->get('marketing'),
        'promotional' => $request->get('promotional'),
        'news' => $request->get('news'),
        'feedback' => $request->get('feedback')
    ];

    foreach ($selections as $selection) {
        if ($selection === null) {
            return $selection = 0);
        }
    }
    dd($selections);
```

Trying to foreach through and check if the checkbox was deselected(null) and set that to zero. I don't think I can do this in my form, but here's that code as well just in case:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label>Uncheck the categories you would like to not receive emails from.</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <br/>
            <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('marketing', '1', true) }}
            Marketing</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <br/>
            <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('promotional', '1', true) }}
            Promotional</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <br/>
            <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('news', '1', true) }}
            News</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <br/>
            <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('feedback', '1', true) }}
            Feedback</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: create 2 checkboxes per checkbox, but make the 1st hidden with value 0. That way you always have a boolean.

Comment: If I recall correctly the `$request->get()` function will return null if no value is set. You could use the php `??` operator to define a default value. I.e. `$request->get('marketing') ?? 0`

Comment: @milo526 or just `$request->input('marketing', 0)`

Comment: ^ That worked great! I also got it to work with a ternary `'marketing' => $request->get('marketing') ? $request->get('marketing') : "0",`, but this is simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer migrated from comment

The problem here is the lack of a default value.
The `$request->get()` function call will return `null` if the value is not in the request which is the case for a unchecked checkbox.
One solution for this problem is the `??` operator in php.

```
$request->get('marketing') ?? 0
```

This essentially says "Take the value of 'marketing', if it is not defined use the value `0`".

Comment: That was actually throwing a syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected '?'`

Comment: Ah. That's PHP 7. This application is built with 5.6.4

Answer (score 0):

It's a practical way for update and create of check boxes and switch buttons  which works perfectly on our website

```
 <label>

    @if($model->exists)
        <!--on edit-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="active" {{$model->active ? 'checked value="1"' : 'value="0"'}}>
    @else
       <!--on create-->
       <input  type="checkbox" name="active" checked value="{{old('active', 1)}}">
    @endif

 </label>
```